# TLS sanity check

Tags: tls

I know there are some tools to check if a certificate is according to the standards like zlint or  if the certificate has been logged. But are there tools that work on the rest of the connection like handshake? Normally it is up to the application or library to check for correct values but consider you have some packet dump and maybe the SSL keylog file. Is there some way to use some other application to check for correctness?

Comment: Zlint checks if certificate meets some requirements. What do you mean by *"if the certificate has been **logged**"*?

Comment: @mentallurg I assume they refer to [certificate transparency logs](https://certificate.transparency.dev/), a process by which the issuing of certificates by a CA is logged with multiple public sources for auditing purposes.

Comment: Tools like Wireshark should work (well, at least it parses the packets, it doesn't necessarily *verify* them). You'd need the master secret of a connection to validate TLS 1.3 and TLS 1.2 (EC)DHE though.

Comment: @mentallurg Yes, i was meaning certificate transparency logs.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes parsing would not be enough. Some tool which checks the parsed and maybe decrypted packets would be nice. Or some way to crosscheck obtained values with some other library.